# Typescript class with no extra definition other than abstract are interchangable

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider this example:

```
abstract class Id {
  public abstract getPrefix(): string;

  // use getPrefix to generate id
}

class UserId extends Id {
  public getPrefix(): string {
    return 'user';
  }
}

class OrganizationId extends Id {
  public getPrefix(): string {
    return 'organization';
  }
}

const getUser = (id: UserId) => {};

const userId = new UserId();
const orgId = new OrganizationId();

getUser(userId);
getUser(orgId); // this should throw an error, but it doesn't
```

Both `UserId` and `OrganizationId` extend the base class `Id` and provide the `abstract` method. When this happens, `userId` and `orgId` are interchangeable - TS does not complain about `getUser(orgId);` while I expect it to do.

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: This is due to TypeScript's structural type system. To enforce stricter type checking, you can use "branding" to differentiate the classes. For example, you can add a private field in the base class and use it in derived classes' constructors. This will prevent instances from being interchangeable even though their structures match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enforce stricter type checking, you can add a private field in the base class and use it in derived classes' constructors. This is known as "branding":

```
abstract class Id {
  private readonly _brand!: void; // Private field for branding

  public abstract getPrefix(): string;
}

class UserId extends Id {
  private readonly _brand!: void; // Private field for branding

  public getPrefix(): string {
    return 'user';
  }
}

class OrganizationId extends Id {
  private readonly _brand!: void; // Private field for branding

  public getPrefix(): string {
    return 'organization';
  }
}

const getUser = (id: UserId) => {};

const userId = new UserId();
const orgId = new OrganizationId();

getUser(userId);
getUser(orgId); // TypeScript will now raise an error here
```

By adding the private `_brand` field, TypeScript treats instances of `UserId` and `OrganizationId` as distinct types, preventing them from being interchangeable in the `getUser` function.

Comment: Thank you! Although remove the `readonly` from the abstract class

Comment: Yes can be removed but using readonly for the `_brand` field helps keep things separate. It's like putting a special sticker on each type so TypeScript knows they're different.